# Cannot access network folder from local server on my machine

Tags: windows-10, networking, network-shares, process

I have network folder (`\\domain.corp\work`), which I can access in a program (executed in terminal) with my user (`filip`) on my machine (`DESKTOP-MI7V4AE`):

```
on host [DESKTOP-MI7V4AE.localhost], domain [DESKTOP-MI7V4AE]
by user [filip]
network folder [\\domain.corp\work] found
```

but when the program is started from our main company program (used to start and stop other programs, such as my own), the output is different and the process then cannot find the network folder. It seems like the corporate program creates some sort of local server with different user (thats just my assumption though):

```
on host [DESKTOP-MI7V4AE.localhost], domain [WORKGROUP]
by user [DESKTOP-MI7V4AE$]
network folder [\\domain.corp\work] not found
```

Does anyone know how I can access the network folder from process created by the local server? Or what is the actual problem here so I can look it up? Thank you in advance

Comment: You should ask your Company technical support about this.

Comment: I did, the problem is no one ever worked with network folders from this program :(

Comment: `DESKTOP-MI7V4AE$` is the local computer account, not a user account.  I suspect your network share **\\domain.corp\work** allows your local user account `filip` to access it, but the local computer account `DESKTOP-MI7V4AE$` is denied.  As John suggests, follow-up with your domain administrators and have them review the share and folder permissions to permit `DESKTOP-MI7V4AE$`.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you guys.

Comment: This may not even apply since it works in one instance and not via the other, but if the previous commenters' advice doesn't resolve the issue and the local share is being accessed by hostname and not IP _(I'm assuming the former due to `\\domain.corp`)_, Windows usually requires three steps to be configured for accessing local shares by hostname only: (1) The share server's _local_ domain name must match the router's _local_ domain name; (2) Windows' Workgroup name must match the _local_ domain name of router and share server; (3) Windows's `hosts` file must have an entry for the share server